# How to list all the log group in Cloudwatch using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

How to I list all the log groups in Cloudwatch using Boto3. When I try the below syntax. I get error.

```
client = boto3.client('logs')

response = client.describe_log_groups(limit=51)
```

> validation error detected: Value '51' at 'limit' failed to satisfy
> constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 50

Based on [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_groups) we could go above 50

> limit (integer) -- The maximum number of items returned. If you don't
> specify a value, the default is up to 50 items.

Comment: similar to this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338687/boto3-cloudwatch-log-returns-only-100-loggroups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, always go to the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogGroups.html), which says the following:

> Valid Range: Minimum value of 1. Maximum value of 50.

To solve your problem, you need to use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html):

```
paginator = logs_client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
for page in paginator.paginate():
    for group in page['logGroups']:
        print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `paginate()` function includes a `build_full_result()` method, eliminating the `for page in paginator.paginate():`

```
paginator = logs_client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
log_groups = paginator.paginate().build_full_result()
for group in page['logGroups']:
    print(group)
```