# Boto3 CloudWatch Log returns only 100 logGroups

Tags: pagination, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, python-3.9

The AWS account I'm dealing with has **300+** CloudWatch LogGroups.
But when I try to retrieve them with nextToken and pagination techniques, **it returns only 100 records**.
I used the below codes.

***nextToken with while loop***

```
response = client.describe_log_groups()
    logGroups = list()
    if response is not None and 'logGroups' in response:
        logGroups = response['logGroups']
    while 'nextToken' in response:
        response = client.describe_log_groups(
            nextToken=response['nextToken'])
        if response is not None and 'logGroups' in response:
            logGroups.extend(response['logGroups'])
```

***Pagination***

```
client = session.client('logs') 
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
for page in paginator.paginate():
    for group in page['logGroups']:
        print(group['logGroupName'])
```

**Software Versions**

Boto3 = 1.23.1

Python = 3.9.4 64Bit

Any clue my dear friends?

Comment: Both examples look fine. Are all the log groups in the same region?

Comment: @jordanm Thanks very much. I didn't notice it. region of the credential file was different from the region I looked at in the console. I was confused with exactly 100 records as batch returns 50 per once. That region also has 100 log groups. My Bad!
Thanks for your time jordanm!

Comment: I've used same code and I'm getting like 16 log group names which should be like 400+. I'm getting error  An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the PutRetentionPolicy operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded, any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: @Maciej, Sorry I didn't get your problem.
Are you using this code to get log groups or a code similar to this to put a Retention policy on them?